# Rejecting an approved document will hide it from the visitor users even if there is a previous approved version for the document

Tags: 2013, list, document-library, library, versioning

I am facing a critical problem inside my SharePoint document library. here is the scenario:-

- I have a team site collection inside SharePoint 2013.
- i add a document library inside the Team site.
- I define the following version setting . where users will only be able to see approved documents (in other word they will see the latest approved version)

[image]

- now when a user upload a new document its status will be pending.
- other users will not see this document since it does not have any approved versions.
- when approver user approve the document, then the document will be visible to all the users.

till now everything is fine.

- let say a user edit the document , add some text, save it , then the document status will be pending.
- and all users will still see the approved version, which sound valid.
- then approver user approve the document , so the pending modification will be viable to all users.. so far everything is working well.

but the problem starts if approver user reject and approved document. where in this case all users will not see the document (not even the latest approved version), although they should be able to see the latest approved version. so why rejecting an approved document will hide it completely from all users, while rejecting a pending document will keep the latest approved version visible to all users ?

Can anyone adivce, is this a bug in sharepoint ?  or there is a reson behind this?

second question. inside my enterprise wiki , approver users can only approve/reject peding wiki pages. for example if the wiki page status is Approved, then the approve/reject will be disabled . while in the document library case the "Approve/Reject" links will always be enabled, so you can directly reject and Approved document unlike the wiki pages ???

Comment: I would use minor versioning on the library as well (to avoid your main problem, the second problem should be a different question..)

Comment: but i do not want to use minor versioning so is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @RobertLindgren seems also if i use minor version ,, i will face similar problem, when you unpublish a document, then edit it,, and publish it again. where in this case the document will not be shown to all users unless you approve it !!! i think in the enterprise wiki page things go better since you can not approve/reject wiki page unless its status is pending ... while in the document library things are uncontrolled.. so how i can fix this problem as our customers start complaining about this,,

Comment: @RobertLindgren since if there are rejected documents inside the document library,, then you can not know if users are able to see their latest approved version or not !!! because this depends on whether you have rejected a pending document or you have rejected an approved document .. this is the most dangerous bug i face in SharePoint 2013 ,, not sure how Microsoft did not notice this !!

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem and only one solution that worked for me when **disable minor version** in Library setting ( last 2 hours confuse me ) and @robert-lindgren comment help me

[image: disable hide options radio button draft approved reject معلق پیش نویس تایید رد شیرپوینت]

when minor enabled , you only two options for draft or suspend