# REST list of built in columns for $select

Tags: 2013, rest

I'm just getting into using REST calls to work with SharePoint 2013. The first challenge I'm facing is know which columns I can retrieve using $select and which ones need to be expanded.

For example I'm using the document id services and want to retrieve the document id. I tried **$select="DocId"** but that didn't work. Eventually I noticed somewhere that it is **OData__dlc_DocId**. How would I have ever guessed that?

I know how to look up the internal name for columns that we've created, but I don't know how to find these names for other built in properties.

Is there a list of these somewhere?

Also is there a list which ones need to be expanded?

Answer (score 1):

I too am in the early months of using the SharePoint (Online) REST APIs and on the whole are liking the experience.

A browser add-in I've found very useful to expand the results of and debug REST API calls is http://restclient.net/

Once I know I've got a successful call, I've found it straightforward to drill down into the results using the `d.results[n]` syntax

Update:
So, I've done some more research now I see you are working with a document library and looking for document properties...

I turns out that the REST URL is slightly different for querying document properties: `https://mysharepointsite/sites/site_name/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/site_name/Document Library Name/File Name.suffix')`

For me, this query returns the following fields:

"CheckInComment": "",
"CheckOutType": 0,
    "ContentTag": "{9874C2F2-DB89-4604-BD13-32E30F5176D2},2,5",
    "CustomizedPageStatus": 0,
    "ETag": "\"{9874C2F2-DB89-4604-BD13-32E30F5176D2},2\"",
    "Exists": true,
    "IrmEnabled": false,
    "Length": "9117",
    "Level": 255,
    "LinkingUrl": "",
    "MajorVersion": 1,
    "MinorVersion": 0,
    "Name": "lifing hazard.jpg",
    "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/dev/Skills Training Images/lifing hazard.jpg",
    "TimeCreated": "2014-03-17T00:30:10Z",
    "TimeLastModified": "2014-03-17T00:30:53Z",
    "Title": "Excessive Weight",
    "UIVersion": 512,
    "UIVersionLabel": "1.0",
    "UniqueId": "9874c2f2-db89-4604-bd13-32e30f5176d2"

where 'Length' is the file size in bytes.

MSDN Source - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx

Comment: That link doesn't work for me. But I don't think every possible field is returned unless you ask for it, right? So if you don't know what it is called, how could you drill down to find out what the name is?

Comment: Not sure why the link didn't work, but its by no means the only REST query add-in out there; probably worth a search around and find one that 'does it' for you.

Comment: As far as REST syntax/results go, eg. `https://mysite/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('mylist')/Items?$filter=ID eq '186'` give me all fields - custom & built in columns - which I can then extract using 'd.results.fieldname'.  Using the browser dev tools with a well-positioned breakpoint has allowed me to query the result in real-time.

Comment: I tried this and it is very helpful--thank you. But it doesn't include all the built in properties. For example I know that there is a FileRef and FileLeafRef, but those are not in the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

I did find [this post](https://dipansaha.wordpress.com/2012/07/23/useful-reference-for-sharepoint-internal-fields-name/). Don't know if it is complete or up to date. Fixe Size and Source URL didn't work for me.

Name               FileLeafRef
Name               LinkFilenameNoMenu
Name               LinkFilename
Name               BaseName
URL Path           FileRef
Path               FileDirRef
File Size          File_x0020_Size
File Type          File_x0020_Type
Source Url         _SourceUrl
Type               DocIcon
Name               FileLeafRef
Title              Title
Order              Order
HTML File Type     HTML_x0020_File_x0020_Type
URL Path           FileRef
Created            Created_x0020_Date
File Size          File_x0020_Size
File Type          File_x0020_Type
File Name          BaseName
Created By         Author
Modified By        Editor

Comment: Found this related question http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/116921/distinguish-between-approved-and-not-approved-items-rest-api Aproval status is called OData__ModerationStatus

Comment: Original answer updated